# Subclassed QWidget does not move correctly

Tags: qt

I have subclassed QWidget as follows:

```
class myClass : public QWidget
{
public:
   explicit myClass(QWidget *parent);
protected:
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
}

myWidget::myWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   setGeometry(10,10,100,100);
}

void myWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
   QPainter qp(this);
   QBrush bBlue(QColor::blue);
   qp.fillRect(geometry(), bBlue);
}
```

What I wanted was to create a blue background QWidget placed onto the QWidget parent at 10,10 of size 100,100.

What I'm getting is a default size for myWidget of something like 100,50 at 0,0 with a black background (or transparent) and a blue rectangle starting at 10,10 within myWidget and clipped by myWidget.

It's like the setGeometry moved a rectangle within myWidget, not the myWidget itself.

Fairly new to Qt and would love an explanation and fix of above...

Thank you in advance.

Gary.

...here is actual code:

this is myWidget

```
class piTemplateWidget : public QWidget
{

public:
        explicit piTemplateWidget(QWidget* parent);

    static QColor* white;
    static QColor* black;
    static QColor* lightGrey;
    static QColor* lightGreen;

    piTemplate* tplt;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};


QColor* piTemplateWidget::white = new QColor(15,15,15);
QColor* piTemplateWidget::black = new QColor(250,250,250);
QColor* piTemplateWidget::lightGrey = new QColor(100,100,100);
QColor* piTemplateWidget::lightGreen = new QColor(250,15,250);

piTemplateWidget::piTemplateWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    tplt = NULL;
    move(100,100);
    resize(300,240);
}

void piTemplateWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter qp(this);

    QBrush bWhite(*white);

    qp.fillRect(this->geometry(), bWhite);

//    if (tplt==NULL)
//        return;

//    tplt->render(&qp);

}
```

...and this is the parent widgets constructor which instantiates my widget

```
piTemplateEdit::piTemplateEdit(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::piTemplateEdit)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    currentTemplate = NULL;
    if (piTemplate::templates->count()>0)
    {
        currentTemplate = (piTemplate*)piTemplate::templates->atIndex(0);
    }
    templateWidget = new piTemplateWidget(this);
    templateWidget->tplt = currentTemplate;
}
```

...I hopes this helps.

Thank you.

Comment: just added actual code...

Comment: Thanks for your help, hopefully you can see the comments below and where I went wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `geometry` during the constructor may get overridden by the `show` event that the parent widget calls on it.

A common main function can look like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    // w.showMaxmized(); // This line would trump the "setGeometry() call 
                         // in the constructor

    return a.exec();
}
```

The geometry rect stored in a QWidget is described here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop

I would not use this internal `QWidget` setting as how you fill your widget.  If you do want to store some setting, make a `QRect` member variable and use that instead.

If you want to fill the entire box of your QWidget with a color you should try something like this:

```
void myWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
   QPainter qp(this);
   QBrush bBlue(QColor::blue);
   qp.fillRect(QRect(0,0, this->width(), this->height()), bBlue);
}
```

Inside paint functions, they are relative to paintable area you are in.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapTo

And like @LaszloPapp was saying, you need to use `resize()` and `move()`.  And it wouldn't hurt to throw in a `update()` call after either one of those.

Also be sure to check out the `show()` method and all of its "See Also" items.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#show

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshowevent.html

If you `#include <QShowEvent>`, and call `resize()` when the show event happens, you may be good to go.  If you are nesting this widget inside another widget you should look into using the size hint and `setFixedSize` or using Layouts properly.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi phyatt. Thanks for your answer. I must need some sleep! The original setGeometry(10,10,100,100) works just fine. It was the fillRect that was in error... as you aspired to - the rect passed in this is relative to QWidget client area and so should be located at 0,0. This is what threw me. I guess you answered my question - many thanks and Cheers!